# How to preserve tiles on screen when generated dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to place a tile on the screen every time a user clicks the 'new' button. My implmementation works, but I cannot get any of the dynamically generated tiles (created from the 'new' button click event) to persist after the app has been closed down and then reloaded. I do not know what the issue is, because when I navigate to other pages in my application and then back to the Tile page, the tiles still persist. What I have is as follows:

TilePage.xaml.cs

```
public TilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateTileList();  //create main tile first always and check if others exist 
    }

private void CreateTileList()
    {
        tileItems = new ObservableCollection<TileItem>()             
        {                
            new TileItem() { ImageUri = mainImage, Title = "main", /*Notification = "",*/ Message = "main", GroupTag = "MainGroup", TileName = "main" },

        };

        //Set the first tile item
        this.tileList.ItemsSource = tileItems;  //sets the tileList Listbox ItemsSource to tileItems ObservableCollection            

        if (Settings.TileList.Value.Count > 0)  //add other tiles accordingly
        {
            foreach (var existingItem in Settings.TileList.Value)
            {
                tileItems.Add(existingItem);
            }
        }

        this.tileList.ItemsSource = tileItems;
    }

void addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage newTileImage = new BitmapImage();

        var newItem = new TileItem() { ImageUri = newTileImage, Title = "new", /*Notification = "",*/ Message = "new browser", GroupTag = "TileGroup", TileName = "new" };
        tileItems.Add(newItem); //update UI immediately
        Settings.TileList.Value.Add(newItem); //update saved TileList
    }
```

I have a Settings.cs class that is used to persist the data in isolated storage via another Setting.cs class

```
public class Settings
{        
    public static Setting<ObservableCollection<TileItem>> TileList = new Setting<ObservableCollection<TileItem>>("TileList", new ObservableCollection<TileItem>());
}
```

I always call the `CreateTileList()` method in the constructor to generate the first tile (which always works no matter what) and then check to see if other tiles have been created by the user. If so, I attempt to add those tiles too (which only works when the app hasnt been closed and then reopened).

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [this link](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings) for `IS settings implementation`. After every Item added you need to save `IS Settings` too. By this your app list will be stored in the IS settings which on load of your application, you need to copy it to your list (tileItems) to which UI has been binded with. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate back from other pages, the main page you're talking about stays cached, and so do the tiles, and that's why you see them.

It seems to me that the error is somewhere in saving/loading data from IsolatedStorage. If you can put a breakpoint at

```
if (Settings.TileList.Value.Count > 0)
```

and examine what's inside Isolated Storage settings tile list, you'll probably notice that nothing is there.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that though and the problem is that when exiting the application in the emulator by pressing anything but the home button breaks the debugger. So I can never navigate back into the application while it is still debugging to check the values.

Comment: Well this also tells you something. There is something wrong with your code which causes the debugger to break. I assume it's the fact that it tries to serialize (store) your lists to Isolated Storage when you're exiting the app, and it can't because there's something wrong with your TileItem - I think that BitmapImage cannot be serialized.